# Rails, devise, acl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, acl

I have followed this tut http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-bootstrap-devise-cancan.html I want to do something like this:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
before_filter :authenticate_VIP!
before_filter :authenticate_admin!
before_filter :authenticate_somerole!
```

I have tables: roles, users, user_roles and I don't want to create another table (rails g devise VIP create another table).

I want to have methods authenticate_ROLE. How to do this ?

Comment: your user has many roles or one role? i means one user can be a vip and admin, or user only can be normal user or vip or admin?

Comment: Not many roles, 1 user = 1 role

Comment: actually i'm only use method `:authenticate_user!` of devise, and with other filters, i use `CanCan` to define abilities of users, example, you can check role of current user, then in your `ability` file of `CanCan`, you can define ability like: `if user.role? "vip": do something...`, others role are the same.

Comment: Kien Thanh: could you put here working example ? (Of all ability file and how to define which actions can access role)

Comment: okey, i will put it in answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have three table, Users, Roles, and RoleRelationships (or role_users, it's up to you)

This is my Role table:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :role_relationships
  has_many :users, through: :role_relationships
end
```

Role table will have `name` column for roles, like: "admin", "teacher", "vip" (as you want).

And this is User table:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise ...
  has_many :role_relationships
  has_many :roles, through: :role_relationships
end
```

and my RoleRelationship table:

```
class RoleRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :role_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

I set up my app one user can have many roles, you can set up your way. So, i have a `role?(role)` method in my `user.rb`, like this:

```
def role?(role)
  return role == RoleRelationship.find_by_user_id(self.id).role.name
end
```

Then in my `abilities` files, i define abilities of users:

```
def initialize(user)

  user ||= User.new # guest user

  if user.role? "teacher"
        can :read, Course
        can :manage, Topic, user_id: user.id
        can :create, Topic
  else  user.role? "admin"
        can :manage, Course
  end
```

So, `teacher` will only read `Course`, and `admin` can CRUD `Course`. To do that, i use method `load_and_authorize_resource` in my CoursesController:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  ...
end
```

Finally, in my views, i used code like this:

```
<% if can? manage, @course %>
   Only admin can work, see what happen here.
<% end %>
```

So, as you see, `teacher` only can read Course so they can't see or do what admin can do, in this case, is create course or edit course.
This is what i built in my online test app, you can reference and do the same for your app.

Comment: Thank you VERY VERY much for your answer. But did this:
    if user.has_role? :vip
        Rails.logger.debug("user.has_role")
        can :show, MsgController
    end
And in controller:
  def show
   authorize! :show , @user, :message => 'You are not VIP'
  end
And I always "not vip" (in logs I have that I am VIP)

Comment: You only can use `can?` with Model in `ability` file, not controller. In controller, you can use `load_and_authorize_resource :only => [:show,...]` or `load_and_authorize_resource :except =? [:show,...]` to restrict actions users can do in controller. You should take care about [Ability Precedence](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence). You should look at the Can Can gem to find what your fits.